# Validating simple RSVP form through PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am trying to validate my RSVP form using only PHP. The user should receive an error message when the form is incomplete. I am trying to avoid the use of jQuery.

I am using this tutorial:
http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/

The form is functioning fine but I haven't been able to get the error messages to display at all. I am using Wordpress and I want the form to appear at the footer of every page; not sure if this complicates matters. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$response = ""; 

//function to generate response
function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message) {

    global $response;

    if ($type == "success") {
        $response = "<div class='success'>{$message}</div>";
    } else { 
        $response = "<div class='error'>{$message}</div>";
    }
}


//response messages
$missing_content = "Please supply all information.";
$email_invalid   = "Email Address Invalid.";
$message_unsent  = "Message was not sent. Try Again.";
$message_sent    = "Thanks! Your message has been sent.";

//variables defined for messages 
$email = $_POST["rsvp_email"]; 
$name = $_POST["rsvp_name"];
$attend = $_POST["rsvp_attend"];
$number = $_POST["rsvp_number"];

//variables defined for message to admin
$to = get_option('admin_email'); //sending to wordpress admin email
$subject = "Just Kidding You Foo"; 
$headers = "From: $email\n";
$message = "$name $attend.\n RSVPs $number of people";

//conditional statements used for form validation

//validate email
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
} else { //email is valid

    //validate presence of name and message
    if(empty($name) || empty($attend) || empty($number)) {
        my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
    } else { //ready to go!
        $sent = wp_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        if($sent) {
            my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //message sent!
        } else {
            my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
        }
    }
}

?>


<div id="page-rsvp">        

    <h1>RSVP</h1>

    <div id="respond">

    <?php echo $response; ?>

    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">               

        <!--Name here-->
        <div class="rsvp-full"><label for="rsvp_name"><input type="text" name="rsvp_name" value="Your name"></label></div>
        <div class="rsvp-full"><label for="rsvp_email"><input type="text" name="rsvp_email" value="Your email"></label></div>

        <!--status of attendance-->
        <div class="rsvp-full">
        <div class="rsvp-element"><input id="radio-button" type="radio" name="rsvp_attend" value="accepts">Accepts</div>
        <div class="rsvp-element"><input id="radio-button" type="radio" name="rsvp_attend" value="declines">Declines</div>
        </div>    

        <!--number of guests attending-->                    
        <div class="rsvp-full"><input type="number" name="rsvp_number" min="1" max="5">Total number of guests attending</div>    

         <div id="submit-button" class="rsvp-full"><input id="submit-button" type="submit"></div>

    </form> 

    </div>  


</div>
```

TIA!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with WP, but if I understand correctly, I believe you're trying to ensure all the fields are filled out.

***Check your brackets!*** You need to be sure your curly brackets are opening and closing where you want them to. Otherwise the output of the page won't display. I write in all my braces because I'm not smart enough to be sure I know where they start and stop. I've taken the liberty of editing them into your question. I believe there was one missing at the end.

Once I fixed the brackets and removed functions my computer didn't have, it worked fine.

Tip 0: Try turning error reporting on for this script - `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of this script. I always do for development.

Tip 1: use the `placeholder` attribute instead of `value` for things like "your name".

Tip 2: make sure the `$_POST` vars are set. I would do this by checking if they're set and then setting them to `''` if they aren't; something like this:

```
//variables defined for messages 
// you could do it like this:
if (isset($_POST["rsvp_email"])) {
    $email =  $_POST["rsvp_email"]; 
} else {
    $email = '';
}

// or like this:
$name = '';
if (isset($_POST["rsvp_name"])) {
    $name = $_POST["rsvp_name"];
}

// or even using a ternary operator:
$attend = isset($_POST["rsvp_attend"]) ? $_POST["rsvp_attend"] : '';

//but this will trigger a "Notice" error if the post var isn't set.
$number = $_POST["rsvp_number"];
```